# In Access Continuous Form, how do I set the Default Value to be the previous entry?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access Continuous Form, how do I set the Default Value to be the previous entry?

So if I have a field say "A", and I am entering a whole bunch of rows, in the first row, I enter "1", so for every next row that I enter, I want them to all just automatically have "1" already.

Comment: On a related note, `[Ctrl] + [']` (hold down Control key and press single-quote key) will copy the value of the previous record.  This works right out of the box with no code required.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's for a client, so I need full automation.

Comment: In that case, you might like to capture the arrow up and down to move up and down continuous forms. It is fun and clients like it, because it is what they expect to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the after update event of the control, set the default value to the value of the control.

Answer (score 0):

In after update event:

```
me.[fieldname].defaultvalue = me! [fieldname].value
```

Both of the fieldnames are the same